# HDMI switch used to work now doesn't

Tags: hdmi

Some time ago I noticed that if I switched video sources with my HDMI switch to another Ubuntu box, I couldn't switch back. The source is never restored. It affects my desktop systems but doesn't seem to affect my System76 laptop at all. It wouldn't appear to be anything wrong with the switch since the laptop works fine in all of the ports. Could use some troubleshooting tips. Note that I can still SSH to these boxes from the laptop.

Clue please?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware question. Try turning devices off before switching?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Apparently the default drivers for this nVidia card aren't handling it.  I've gotten around it by installing the proprietary drivers.